# Not enough input arguments using the function size to load a signal - Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have a function in matlab called Features. I'm trying to load the signal but I keep getting the error, `Not enough input arguments` at line 3. I think it has something to do with the size but I can't figure out what the problem is. Can someone please assist me? Thanks.

```
function Features = stFeatureExtraction(signal, fs, win, step) %// line 1

  %// if STEREO ... line 2
  if (size(signal,2) > 1) %// line 3
    signal = (sum(signal,2)/2); % convert to MONO
  end

end
```

Comment: can you show the whole error message? Have you defined your own function called `size` by any chance?

Comment: EDU>> stFeatureExtraction
Error using stFeatureExtraction (line 22)
Not enough input arguments. That's the whole error message. I don't think there is any function called size. I got the code from a book and all the associated functions don't seem to have a function called size but I will check again and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: Ok then it's probably the way you call `stFeatureExtraction` that causes the problem. How do you call it? In the Command Window or in a script?

Comment: In the script I guess. I just run the script in the Editor.

Comment: You mean you press the "Run" button in the Editor? If so that's the problem. What if you call the function in the Command Window for example with 4 input arguments?

Comment: You are right. It worked. I called the function in the command line and the error cleared. Thanks a lot. I'm curious to know why pressing the Run button wouldn't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because the function needs inputs. If you hit Run it doesn't provide inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and your help.

Comment: you're welcome! Have fun!